# Set height of div that has dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to set the height of a div so it can be scrolled all the way through. This div is alongside another one, so I had set the overflow-y to scroll. Naturally, I thought that I would have to set the height to auto, so I did. I also tried doing this in Javascript, with no luck. The problem is that the elements of this DIV will change depending on what the users put on their page.

This is my CSS for the div

```
#shiftToRight {
height: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And this is my div:

```
<div id="shiftToRight">
    <div class="profile">
      <h1>Admin Panel</h1>
      <h4 id="editable"><a href="" class="edit-link"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit Image</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="bar"></div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>John Doe 5th Class</h1>
      <h3>Donec auctor tellus id metus venenatis finibus. Cras in elit.</h3>
      <a href="#" id="editable"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
      <div id="minor-bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the height is auto, it will be as tall as it's content, so there will be no scroll. If you give it a fixed height that is less than the height of the content, you can scroll with overflow: scroll

Comment: if you set your height to auto, the div is getting bigger and bigger related by the content. you have to set it to a fixed height or a max-height if you want to see the overflow effect.

Comment: But how would I find that fixed height? The elements in the div will change... I've tried setting it in JS, but with no luck.

Comment: It might be best to use tables for this so that the contents of the largest div can increase the height of the shorter one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by setting `position: absolute` and setting 'left' dynamically in JavaScript to position itself against the other window.

Answer (score 0):

Add a fixed height value if you want to scroll it. Otherwise I am confused by what exactly you are asking:

```
   #shiftToRight {
        height: 200px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: My problem is getting that fixed height. The elements of the div will change depending on the user's number of elements they put on their page

Comment: You make up the fixed height! Whatever you want it to be based on your best estimate! Are you saying there are multiple child divs that could have different heights? Well give each child div a max fixed height then!

Comment: Why would I do that? That would only limit the user to how much they can put on the document. I don't know how much the user could put on their page - if they will put a lot or nothing at all.

Comment: You can still put as much content as you want, it will just be a 200px div that they can scroll through all the content. Otherwise set the height to auto but then each of your divs will be as high as the content. I don't know how else to explain it, if you have a specific layout question then provide a visual and I can help you out more. The code you provided doesn't really help us understand what you want for a final product.